# Active Directory based custom authorization

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application that needs to decide whether or not to return information from controller end points based on the requesting client's Active Directory groups. I tried to implement custom authorization as follows:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddAuthorization(options=> {
                options.AddPolicy("RequiredADGroupName", policy=>policy.Requirements.Add(new ActiveDirectoryRequirement("RequiredADGroupName")));
            });

        }
```

ActiveDirectoryRequirement.cs

```
public class ActiveDirectoryRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public string ActiveDirectoryGroupName { get; set; }

        public ActiveDirectoryRequirement(string groupName)
        {
            ActiveDirectoryGroupName = groupName;
        }
    }
```

ActiveDirectoryHandler.cs

```
public class ActiveDirectoryHandler: AuthorizationHandler<ActiveDirectoryRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ActiveDirectoryRequirement requirement)
        {
            //authorization logic
        }
    }
```

this next one is just an example of how i would use this authorization.
HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
[Authorize(Policy = "RequiredADGroupName")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

When i run the project, i get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme found.
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/02/20/role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-with-azure-ad.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to register `IAuthorizationHandler` with `ActiveDirectoryHandler` like:

```
            services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("RequiredADGroupName", policy =>
            {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new ActiveDirectoryRequirement("RequiredADGroupName"));
            });
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ActiveDirectoryHandler>();
```